# Highlighting values in one column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The problem,

column A has unique employee id's only.

Column B contains the same id's from column A with 1 or more instances but also has it's own duplicates i.e. there are id's in column B in that are not found in column A in duplicate form.

It is these duplicates only found in column B that I want to highlight / remove / filter etc.

**Sample Data Screenshot**
[image]

remove the duplicates in red and keep the ones in green

Help much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write this simple formula in E2

> =IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$10,C2)>0,C2,"")

Answer (score 0):

Select ColumnC, clear any CF from it and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=AND(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$10,C1)=0,COUNTIF(C:C,C1)>1)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select red font, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.